# Multiple points (data set) into function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am creating a 1x5 double (`x = 1:.5:3`), and wish to evaluate all of the values in a function that I'm creating (`f = @(x) 3+2*x + 3*x^2`)

Is it also possible to store this into single column matrix? I wish to do this same process with different x values, say (`x = 1:1:3`) and compare values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = 1:.5:3;
f = @(x) 3+2.*x + 3*x.^2;
mat(:,1) = f(x); %// result
```

The syntax `variablename(:,1)` allows you to store things as a column matrix. Note the `.*` in the function, since you want to apply this operation *elementwise*  and not as a whole matrix. If you want to store more columns, simply change the `1` to `2` and so forth.

Comment: I'm getting the error: Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator when using the ".x" syntax?

Comment: Yes, my bad. The dot should go before the operator, not the variable. I updated my code accordingly

Comment: ah, got it, thank you! is it possible to call upon specific locations of this new matrix? say I want to compute the difference between (3,1) and (4,1)?

Comment: 1) This is dead basic MATLAB. 2) do **NOT** ask questions after your initial question has been answered. If this answer helped you, accept it in due time (there's a 15 minute delay) and ask a new question if you have another question. As for the solution: yes, obviously. `mat(3,1)-mat(4,1)`